# Getting all the POJO items that match max value of a POJO variable

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a POJO class from which I want to collect all the POJO objects that matches the max value of a given POJO variable.

I have the below POJO class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class IPTraceData implements Serializable {

    private String factId;
    private long startIp;
    private long endIp;
    private int confidence;
    private LocalDate date;
    private long ipaddr;
}
```

I want to get all the POJO object which match with the max value of **confidence** variable.

I am able to get the results using the below code in Java 8.

```
int max = allTraces.stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(IPTraceData::getConfidence))
            .get()
            .getConfidence();

List<IPTraceData> traceData = allTraces
            .stream()
            .filter(m -> m.getConfidence() == max)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, I am trying to write a code in Java 8 using a single stream statement.
How can I achieve the same using the single stream statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically it's is possible to implement that logic with a **single statement**. But this solution has an additional cost of allocating in memory an intermediate map `Map<Integer,<List<IPTraceData>>`.

The approach of finding the **max confidence** first and then processing the data set based on it is more performance-wise.

```
List<IPTraceData> traceData = allTraces
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(IPTraceData::getConfidence))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

**Note:**

- avoid using `get()` with optional when code doesn't contain any checks that ensure that the optional object is not empty. If you expect it not to be empty and your intention is to make the code fail to emphasize the problem use `orElseThrow()` instead. That'll make your intention more clear.

Comment: Clever, but grouping might not work depending on the equals & hashCode definition

Comment: @Andronicus As a rule of thumb if an object is intended to be used with **collections** it must override `hashCode()` and `equals()` . Or you have another opinion on that point?

Comment: Yes, but we don't know how `Confidence` looks like. It might have another field, then two objects with the same `confidence` value would be different objects.

Comment: @Andronicus Take a look at the code in the question it's plain integer primitive. All objects with the same `confidence` will be grouped together in a list (doesn't matter if they are the same or different according to `equals()`). The map type will be `Map<Integer, <List<IPTraceData>>`.

Comment: You're right, I don't know why I thought there's a special `Confidence` object, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Andronicus It's OK

Comment: _Technically it's is possible_ Your solution is not much different from the one of the Op. Just more complicated. You also have two streams, one collecting one reducing.

Comment: @abetteroliver I've pointed out that the code listed is better. It's just an example of a **single-statement** solution (as it was required) that is not applicable for real-life scenarios. And sure, I'm aware that my code creates two streams.

Comment: Fair point, Alexander. I have interpreted _single stream statement_ differently.

Comment: @abetteroliver Pipelines that spawn other pipelines aren't evil it's a part of a concept of Streams. It could be useful for instance when flattening stream elements. Another thing is the usage of convoluted nested streams and excessive chaining. That's the true evil.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without additional intermediate memory usage, and fully parallelizable, you can use the general `collect` functionality. Something like this (untested; feel free to extract methods to make it more readable):

```
List<IPTraceData> traceData = allTraces.stream()
    .collect(
        // supplier
        ArrayList::new,

        // accumulator
        (r, t) -> {
          if (r.isEmpty()) {
            r.add(t);
          } else {
            int currentMaxConfidence = r.get(0).getConfidence();
            if (t.getConfidence() == currentMaxConfidence) {
              r.add(t);
            } else if (t.getConfidence() > currentMaxConfidence) {
              r.clear();
              r.add(t);
            }
          }
        },

        // combiner
        (left, right) -> {
          if (left.isEmpty()) {
            left.addAll(right);
          } else if (!right.isEmpty()) {
            int leftMax = left.get(0).getConfidence();
            int rightMax = right.get(0).getConfidence();

            if (leftMax == rightMax) {
              left.addAll(right);
            } else if (leftMax < rightMax) {
              left.clear();
              left.addAll(right);
            }
          }
        }
    );
```

You can also do the same thing with non-mutable data structures using `reduce()` instead of `collect()`, but using the normal Java lists is a bit of a pain in a non-mutable way.

Note that I'm aware that the code is quite unwieldy and probably not worth it, but I'm purely answering your question without any assumptions about how and where you want to use it.